# VB.NET How to get integer from Request

Tags: vb.net, request

I want to get an integer from the URL querystring, but I want to protect against strings being entered. So for example;

```
http://mydomain.com/index.aspx?page=1

Dim iPageID as Integer = Request("page")
```

I want to get the '1' and save it as an integer variable, but the page errors out if I enter the below address;

```
http://mydomain.com/index.aspx?page=string
```

I've tried using CInt and CType, but that just brings a 'string cannot be converted to integer' issue. I'm sure there's something simple I can do, but I've been banging my head against the wall for almost an hour now and I just want to get this small thing sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Request.QueryString` and `Int32.Parse` to convert the string `"1"` to the `Integer` 1.

```
Dim iPageID as Integer = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString("page"))
```

If you ant to ensure that the querystring is valid use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

```
Dim iPageID as Integer
If Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString("page"), iPageID) Then
     ' valid, do something ...
Else
     ' invalid
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

How about rather using [Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.